# awk/bash compare timestamp and sort time diff across row

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

i have a log file like this:

```
2019-10-15 13:35:46.823 INFO : xxx
2019-10-15 13:35:46.886 INFO : yyy
2019-10-15 13:35:46.943 INFO : zzz
2019-10-15 13:35:47.822 INFO : aaa
2019-10-15 13:35:48.824 INFO : bbb
```

i need to find out the time difference (in ms) between the timestamp for consecutive lines, and sort by the time difference (the first line is ignored)

```
 2019-10-15 13:35:46.823 1571117746823
 2019-10-15 13:35:48.824 1002
 2019-10-15 13:35:47.822 879
 2019-10-15 13:35:46.886 63
 2019-10-15 13:35:46.943 57
```

i am able to do this by writing a bash script like

```
lastEpoch=0
while read p; do
  logTime=$(echo $p | cut -c1-24)
  currentEpoch=$(date -d "$logTime" +%s%3N)
  log="$log $logTime$((currentEpoch-$lastEpoch))"$'\n'
  lastEpoch=$currentEpoch  
done < my.log
echo -e "$log" > tmp.log
sort -nrk3 tmp.log
```

but it takes very long time to run the script, as my original log files has 1M lines, and I guess I am not using the most efficient way to do this

i think awk can do this efficiently but I am very new to awk, can someone give me hints on how to do this on awk..? or is there any more efficient way?

Comment: I would run the script without sorting to see how long it lasts in order to know if it is the sort operation that is heavy or the conversions of dates.

Comment: I wonder if your code `$((currentEpoch-$lastEpoch))` shouldn't be `$(($currentEpoch-$lastEpoch))` (mind the "$" sign at the beginning of the bash expression.

Comment: @PierreFrançois yes there is a missing $, don't know why the script still works in this case

Comment: I just discovered that the presence of the '$' is not mandatory in bash expressions. So, if `a=2;b=5` you can issue `echo $(($a + $b))` as well as `echo $((a + b))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F' INFO|: ' '
{
  split($1,array,"[- :.]")
  current=mktime(array[1] " " array[2] " " array[3] " " array[4] " " array[5] " " array[6]) * 1000 + array[7]
  print $1,$2,current-prev
  prev=current
}
' Input_file  | sort -r -nk3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in bash and convert the dates with `while read` loop and `date` to convert the date to seconds, then subtract it from previous value and print. But, as you discovered, calling `date` for each line is very, very slow.

The difference can be calculated in `awk` with `mktime` function, but you have to first convert to a format `mktime` can eat. Then sort.

```
awk '{
    match($1 " " $2, /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/, t)
    now = mktime(t[1] " " t[2] " " t[3] " " t[4] " " t[5] " " t[6]) * 1000 + t[7] 
    diff = now - prev
    prev = now
    print $1 " " $2 " " diff
}' | sort -r -n -k3
```